# Dynamically creating layout components from database in Android

Tags: android, database, android-activity

For my sample Application I need to create activity components dynamically from my database. Say I have different activities for different illnesses to capture the info from a user, this is the normal way of doing it, but I do not want to create so many activities.

I want to store activity and its component related information in a database (not sqlite) and when the user selects an illness in MainActivity, I will load the components from database and show related components in another activity which is defined in ManifestFile(I know we cannot create Activities dynamically, we must have entry in ManifestFile for a activity).

Comment: Simply have **1** Activity and then swap **Fragments** inside it, as needed.

Comment: i think i need to create different fragments  for this which is similar to different Activities, isn't it?

Comment: Fragments are contained in Activities, but a single Activity can swap any number of Fragments. And Fragments don't have to be declared in the manifest.

Comment: But each fragment will need one layout file right, i dont want to create different layout files,  the core problem here is i will have a layout and i will lay the components which are returned from database, the database will have info like component type,size of component,relative position.etc..

Comment: ha ha..tell me if am not clear..or this is not the correct approach..tqs

Comment: I think it is the hardest (possible?) way to do build an UI.